# Make side by side views always touch each other?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have 2 views, the blue one and the pink one, and I have their constraints set up so they are both a certain percentage of the height, and the blue is 25% of the width, and the pink is 75% of the width. I also have it set so the distance between both of those views and the green header is 0, and the distance between both of the views and their respective sides is 0. When I run it on the iPhone 6s plus sim, it looks great, but any other device and this white line appears. How can I make it so the distance between the two views is always 0? Xcode doesnt seem to want to let me... Any help much appreciated. [Here is the view controller in storyboard,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naYlh.png) / [and here it is when ran in the iPhone 5s sim.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoFCf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your images, the views should not be so far apart unless there are conflicting constraints.

As you have a zero horizontal spacing constraint between `pinkView` and `blueView`, you shouldn't need to specify both 25% / 75% width constraints.

```
|-0-pinkView(@25%-superview-width)-0-blueView-0-|
```

Horizontal constraints similar to above should be enough to prevent any gap (not in strict Visual Constraint Language format).

Comment: xcode isnt telling me of any conflicting constraints, and I cant specify 0 horizontal spacing. For example when i try to put horizontal spacing on the left edge of the pink view, it assumes that its closest neighbor is the edge of the view conroller, not the right edge of the blue view. How do i get those two views to stick to each other?

Comment: _Ctrl_-dragging between the two views either in the scene or in the _Document Outline_ pane of Interface Builder should give you a _Horizontal Spacing_ option (as long as you are dragging in a horizontal line in your scene)

Answer (score 0):

How are you making your views? The most dependable way, I've found is to define your views programmatically. 
Set the screen width and screen height

```
 CGFloat screenWidth=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
 CGFloat screenHeight=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
```

This gives you references based on your device

```
UIView *someView=[UIView alloc]initwithframe:CGRectMake(screenWidth/2,screenHeight/8,screenWidth/4,screenHeight*6/8);
```

Setting views this way will let you just do the ratios for everything to match up and will work for every view.
just so you know

```
someView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addsubview:someView];
```

that changes the colour and adds someView to the view..